# How to run Amazon CLI "glacier" under Python 2.7 on Centos6?

Tags: centos, python, aws

On Centos 6 after installing Amazon's CLI tools using pip:

```
# glacier vaults
```

Result:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Also, `pip check` complains in red text about Python 2.6 deprecation and gives `InsecurePlatform Warning`.

I installed Python 2.7 but read that switching to it by default will break `yum`. Also, for Python 2.6 I installed every recommended module I could find. (Maybe I missed one!) Easiest thing would be to use Python 2.7 it seems to me.

How can I configure Amazon CLI tools like `glacier` to use Python 2.7?

Comment: Seems it does not know the root certificate, or it is expired, or you have to install an intermediate one.